# Can you detect which component was tapped in an Intents UI extension?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have a UI extension for a Siri Shortcut and the I want the view I'm displaying within Siri to do different things when different parts are clicked. For example, I am displaying some contact information for a contact from a different system, and I'd like to call the phone number when the phone number is clicked, and to open the map with directions when the address is clicked. I'm able to detect when the app is opened because *anything in the view* was clicked, but I can't detect the specific element that was clicked.

This is the gist of my code, with parts removed for brevity.

```
class IntentViewController: UIViewController, INUIHostedViewControlling {

    func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {
        let viewSize = configureUI(with: intent, of: interaction)
        completion(true, [], viewSize)
    }

    private func configureUI(with intent: PersonInfoIntent, of interaction: INInteraction) -> CGSize {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        addChild(vc)
        view.addSubview(vc.view)

        let nameLabel = UILabel(text: name)
        vc.view.addSubview(nameLabel)

        let phoneLabel = UILabel(text: phoneNumber)
        vc.view.addSubview(phoneLabel)

        let addressLabel = UILabel(text: address)
        vc.view.addSubview(address)

        // This does not result in openMap being called
        // let addressTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openMap))
        // addressLabel.addGestureRecognizer(addressTapped)

        return self.extensionContext!.hostedViewMaximumAllowedSize
    }
}
```

I've tried using a `UIButton` and `addTarget` rather than a `UILabel` with a gesture recognizer, but that also never triggers `openMap`.

I'd like to be able to detect which element was tapped so I can set it on my `activity.userInfo` and pick it up in my `AppDelegate.application(_:,continue:,restorationHandler:)`, where I can perform actions like opening the map with directions, or calling a phone number.